# How to create inline for a model with common referenced model in Django admin?

Tags: django

So I have these kind of models:

```
def Profile(models.Model):
    user = OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)

def OtherProfile(models.Model):
    user = OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)

def Item(models.Model):
    user = ForeignKey(User)
```

And I want to have `ItemInline` in `ProfileAdmin` (and similarly in `OtherProfileAdmin`). I tried doing it like this:

```
class ItemInline(admin.TabularInLine):
    model = Item

@admin.register(Profile)
class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ItemInline]
```

However, this shows me this error:

```
<class 'app.admin.ItemInline'>: (admin.E202) 'api.Item' has no ForeignKey to 'api.Profile'.
```

How do I put the `ItemInline` into `ProfileAdmin`?

I can't put `ForeignKey(Profile)` into the `Item`, because then I would not be able to access `Item` from `OtherProfile`.

Comment: Maybe because your `Item` model references `User` model and not `Profile`.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to add inline you have to create a FK (Foreign Key) to it.

*models.py*

```
def Profile(models.Model):
    user = ForeignKey(User)

def Item(models.Model):
    user = ForeignKey(Profile)
```

*admin.py*

```
class ItemInline(admin.TabularInLine):
    model = Item

@admin.register(Profile)
class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ItemInline]
```

Comment: sorry but this is out of the question. A detail that I thought was irrelevant but apparently is, is that there are 2 kinds of profile objects and `item` must be linked to the `user`, so both kinds of profile have access to it. I have edited the question to clear this up.